# Running Python Script through Task Scheduler(or double clicking the .py file) not running

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks

I have a very simple issue that I have been researching and still not found an answer to. I have basic python script that scrapes a website for betting odds, and then writes everything to a csv. I have been messing around with many different formats for inputting. I wrote it in the Spyder ide so as of now in Task Scheduler my "Program/Script" input is:

C:\Users\path\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe

and then my argument line is:

\\serverconnection\path\moneylineScraper.py

The script runs fine when I run it in Spyder, but through double click, bat file, or task scheduler it does not run.

I feel as if I am missing something pretty simple. Whenever the time it is set for to run comes a terminal opens and closes in about 2 seconds on my monitor. Exactly the same as what happens if I double click my script.py file. If anyone has any suggestions, I appreciate the help.

Comment: I would also like to add that when I double click my .py file and the terminal opens fora second I was able to read the last line in it and it says something along the lines of "ImportError No Module named Pandas" but when I use pip install pandas it states requirements already satisfied. As stated before, Pandas imports fine when I run the script in Spyder.

Comment: Can you run it from a cmd prompt manually not the IDE?

Comment: @TWReever Yes I can and it works on my local version. However, I need it to work on a network connection with a path linke \\network\path. I followed the answer in this question https://superuser.com/questions/282963    to test it, and it also worked. This makes me think that I cannot access the network connection from Task Scheduler